# How to make a onPress function return a string value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a onPress button which I use to update the username.
In this button I call a function which checks the username and will return a message if it is a success or not.

Currently I do not know how to do this and I am wondering if it is possible in React or not, and if it isn't how I should be doing it instead.

I am calling the function in EditProfileScreen but how do I make it return the message after the function is called.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can render text on the EditProfileScreen regarding the message the user has gotten after pressing the button and changing there username.

**EditProfileScreen.js**

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import styles from "./styles"; //styles
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { writeUserName } from "../../hooks/useWriteDb";

//view for editing profile
const EditProfileScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");

  const { user } = useAuth();
  return (
    <View styles={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Edit Profile </Text>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Username"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        onChangeText={(text) => setUserName(text)}
        value={username}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: "#9D3BEA" }]} //TODO: change to global styles
        onPress={() => writeUserName(user.uid, username)}
{//This is where I call the function in which I want it to return the message (msg)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Change username</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default EditProfileScreen;
```

**useWriteDb**

```
import { db } from "../model/config"; // import the db config
import { get, ref, child, update } from "firebase/database";
import { DevSettings, View } from "react-native";

function writeUserName(userId, username) {
  // write the username to the db, if the name is already in the system, it will not be written

  const msg = "";
  if (username == "") {
    msg = ("username is null");
    return;
  }

  if (username.length > 20) {
    msg =("username is too long");
    return;
  }

  if (username.length < 3) {
    msg =("username is too short");
    return;
  }
  //check if username already exisits
  //check if username exists in firebase
  get(child(ref(db), "users/")).then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const users = snapshot.val();
      for (const user in users) {
        if (users[user].username == username) {
          console.warn("username already exists");
          return false;
        }
      }
      update(ref(db, "users/" + userId), {
        username: username,
      });
      msg = ("username updated");
    }
  });
}

function retriveUserData(userId) {
  get(child(ref(db), "users/"))
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      } else {
        console.log("No data available");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

export { writeUserName, retriveUserData };
```

Comment: Event handlers don’t return values, but you could have your function call a set state function (or update a variable, a store, or context, etc) such that the component can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you would like to achieve within TouchableOpacity, but you can retrieve the value from the component with state like the following.

```
const [msg, setMsg] = useState("")
...
const getMsgHandler(msgFromTouchableOpacity) {
    setMsg(msgFromTouchableOpacity)
}
<TouchableOpacity onTrigger={getMsgHandler} />
```

Hope it helps.